# Error crawling through locally hosted website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to crawl through a website, which is currently hosted locally. Isn't it possible to crawl locally hosted website? I am getting this error:

```
 File "C:/Users/hero/PycharmProjects/project/Crawler.py", line 22, in <module>
    imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.1.1/Webpage.html"+img_src).read())
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

The code for crawler:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata


i = 1
soup = make_soup("http://192.168.1.1/Webpage.html")

unique_srcs = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    if img.get('src') not in unique_srcs:
        unique_srcs.append(img.get('src'))
for img_src in unique_srcs:
    filename = str(i)
    i = i + 1
    imagefile = open(filename + '.png', 'wb')
    imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.1.1/Webpage.html"+img_src).read())
    imagefile.close()
```

Comment: Hello. It might sound like a dumb question but have you tried to access http://192.168.1.1/Webpage.html with your browser? What about your network? 192.168.1.1 is generally the ip address of the router and I would be surprised if it were the ip of your web server.

Comment: 192.168.1.1 that is the ip I kept for just posting the question. But when I keep my own ip it is working. But, there is error wile crawling

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a slash `/` in the url path.

Just change the line to something like this:

`imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.1.1/Webpage.html/"+img_src).read())`

Comment: I am still getting the same error : urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: What's the value of the variable `img_src` before running this statement?

Comment: It is just to run the for loop. The unique_src consists of those src whose images are not yet crawles

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Just add a `print(img_src)` before `imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.1.1/Webpage.html/"+img_src).read())`. Just to check that any unwanted value is not present in the list.